# uploading videos to server using PHP

Tags: php

I am developing a website which features, users can upload their videos to the website and the videos goes to the server. It perfectly working no problem. But i want to make the below code differently ,when a user uploads the video,it must get stored to new folder in server by creating tht new folder directory(with name as username) and i must be able to fetch it from the server by embedding the video in their respective profiles. 
Below the snippets are commonly used for uploading by creating an upload folder in the server(upload folder was created manually,I want it in a way tht when user uploads the video a new directly must be formed autonomously in server with name as of the username on it) please help.....

```
       video.php
      ----------
       <form action="videophp.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
       <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
       <br />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
       </form>

        videophp.php
       -------------
       <?php

       $allowedExts = array("mp4", "flv","jpg","JPEG");
       $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

       if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")

       || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/flv")
       || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
       || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/JPEG")


         )

          && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2000000)
          && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

         {
           if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
         {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
          }
          else
         {
          echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
          echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
           echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
          echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
       {
         echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else
      {
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
        "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
       }
        }
         else
           {
          echo "Invalid file";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one part of what you're looking for:

```
$username = 'Max Mustermann';    // you'd have to get that from somewhere
$targetfolder = 'upload/'.$username;

if (!file_exists($targetfolder)) {
    mkdir($targetfolder, 0777, true);
}
if (file_exists($targetfolder . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
     echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}
else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
        $targetfolder . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    echo "Stored in: " . $targetfolder . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
```

You still need to send a username to the server.
With that you can also access is on his next visit.

*BUT*
I recommend to give the folder and the file other names and store them in db, connected to the user's data. This way you have better control of who can access what file (video), you don't have to search the filesystem (which is slower then searching n db).

Comment: thanks @Jeff I really  like the code and also appreciate your help. "You still need to send a username to the server. With that you can also access is on his next visit." this part i didnt get .. can u say it in different way ?

Comment: Well, I'm using a variable `$username`, which is not filled with real data yet, because in your example there is no username sent to the server. I don't know how you manage user-sessions now. Maybe you are using cookies? Or a php-session?

Comment: This code is working not as i wanted , there is a small mistake i get , it was my error i askd it the way , the uploaded video must go into the folder created. I have edited my question now.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
   $filename = basename($_FILES['media']['name']);

    $raw = $uploaddir . $filename;
 $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['media']['tmp_name'], $raw))
        $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/newsapp/".$raw;
```

Comment: Could you please also add an explanation of your code?